# Identify trends using pandas and stock prices

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a .head(8) of my df. It shows the date, name, macd, macd_signal, and macd_hist.

```
        Date    Name    macd    macd_signal macd_hist
364 2021-05-03  ACCD    0.889189    0.643972    0.245218
364 2021-05-04  ACCD    0.660302    0.647238    0.013064
364 2021-05-05  ACCD    0.455899    0.608970    -0.153071
267 2021-05-03  ACN     5.011330    5.581300    -0.569971
267 2021-05-04  ACN     4.809930    5.427030    -0.617098
267 2021-05-05  ACN     4.558230    5.253270    -0.695034
268 2021-05-03  ADBE    9.011790    11.57670    -2.56486
268 2021-05-04  ADBE    6.779280    10.61720    -3.83789
268 2021-05-05  ADBE    4.944930    9.482730    -4.5378
```

What I am interested in is to return the last row of each distinct Name where macd_hist has decreased three days in a row.

This means all distinct Names from 2021-05-05 should be returned as they all have macd_hist decreasing day by day.

Output:

```
        Date    Name  macd      macd_signal macd_hist
268 2021-05-05  ADBE  4.944930  9.482730    -4.5378
267 2021-05-05  ACN   4.558230  5.253270    -0.695034
364 2021-05-05  ACCD  0.455899  0.608970    -0.153071
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

```py
def get_last_of_3(g):
    # See How Many Decreases In a Row
    c = g.macd_hist.diff().fillna(-1).lt(0).sum()
    if c != 3:
        # Return Nothing if not 3 decreases
        return None
    # Return Last Row if has 3
    return g.tail(1)


df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False) \
    .apply(get_last_of_3) \
    .droplevel(0, 0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Date  Name      macd  macd_signal  macd_hist
364  2021-05-05  ACCD  0.455899      0.60897  -0.153071
267  2021-05-05   ACN  4.558230      5.25327  -0.695034
268  2021-05-05  ADBE  4.944930      9.48273  -4.537800
```

Comment: Works well! And if I wanted it the other way around, to look for uptrends, how would I modify it?

Comment: `.fillna(1).gt(0)`